# How to set the request cookie when to post form with python3?

Tags: python, cookies, request, response

I want to get an api key automatically with python code.
Here is what I do by hand to get the api key.

1. By hand:

   1. Open `https://www.alphavantage.co` in firefox
   2. click `Get your Free API Key Today`
   3. input `first_name` `last_name` `email`
   4. click the `get free api key`.

[image]

2.By code.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import http.cookiejar

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key'
params = {
          "first": "xx",
          "last": "yy",
          "occupation": "investor",
          "email":"zz@qq.com"
}

headers = {
"Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
"Connection":"keep-alive",
"Content-Length":"77",
"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"Cookie":"csrftoken=qTbVt3HN2VYiDbJgX1n9DdyaDUYKpMyJ1UvTE3xCplYZcAYk9OQaXJ1F6ACadcjA; _ga=GA1.2.1054357644.1509295038; _gid=GA1.2.1986003924.1509295038; _gat=1",
"Host":"www.alphavantage.co",
"Origin:https":"//www.alphavantage.co",
"Referer:https":"//www.alphavantage.co/support/",
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.91 Safari/537.36",
"X-CSRFToken":"l7RRVpYomq6fIvjAnuYJiR0xquqoeD5gXrlowpQqejCCKX65OUrUcZzw2ljf9SPB",
"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
}

postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode()
user_agent = r'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'

cookie = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar()
handler = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
request = urllib.request.Request(LOGIN_URL, postdata, headers)
response = opener.open(request)
```

An error info:

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 499: Client Disconnected
```

The cookie in headers is a request cookie, created in step1.2.

How do I get the api key with python code instead of by hand?

[target website](https://www.alphavantage.co/)

Comment: Hi, from my understanding, once you get an API key from this site, you can keep using that API key from then on. You then use that API key to make queries to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import http.cookiejar

LOGIN_URL1 = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key'

cookie = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar()
handler = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
request = urllib.request.Request(LOGIN_URL1)
response = opener.open(request)
for item in cookie:
    x=item.value

LOGIN_URL2 = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/create_post/'
params = {
"first_text": "xx",
"last_text": "yy",
"occupation_text": "Investor",
"email_text": "cc@bb.cc"
}

headers = {
"Referer": "https://www.alphavantage.co/support/",
"Cookie": "csrftoken={0}".format(x),
"X-CSRFToken":"{0}".format(x)
}

postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode()
req = urllib.request.Request(LOGIN_URL2, postdata, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
print(response.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code.

First. POST request should be sent to the `/create_post/` endpoint.

Second. Field names are different:

```
params = {
    "first_text": "xx",
    "last_text": "yy",
    "occupation_text": "investor",
    "email_text":"zz@qq.com"
}
```

And you need only three headers: `Referer`, `Cookie`, `X-CSRFToken`

Full code:

```
import requests


headers = {
    "Referer": "https://www.alphavantage.co/support/",
    "Cookie": "csrftoken=YOURTOKEN",
    "X-CSRFToken":"YOURTOKEN"
}
params = {
    "first_text": "a",
    "last_text": "b",
    "occupation_text": "Student",
    "email_text": "aa@bb.cc"
}
response = requests.post("https://www.alphavantage.co/create_post/",
                         data=params, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```